# Page styles only work for \thispagestyle under afterpage

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, afterpage

Using [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to set a page style *after* some page only works for `\thispagestyle`, but not for `\pagestyle`. Why is that? How can I make it work?

`\lipsum[1-20]` produces 4 pages of text, *Lorem Ipsum* style. So, the following document consists of 8 pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,afterpage,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyhdr,afterpage,lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{pagestyleA}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[C]{pagestyleA}% Header
  \fancyfoot[C]{A--\thepage}% Footer
}
\fancypagestyle{pagestyleB}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[C]{pagestyleB}% Header
  \fancyfoot[C]{B--\thepage}% Footer
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{\thispagestyle{pagestyleA}}\lipsum[1-20]
\clearpage
\afterpage{\pagestyle{pagestyleB}}\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Using `\afterpage{\thispagestyle{pagestyleA}}` at the start prints page 2 with page style `pagestyleA`.

[image]

It is expected that the second `\afterpage{\pagestyle{pagestyleB}}` should deliver pages 6-8 with page style `pagestyleB`. However, it does nothing...

[image]

Comment: The token list in the argument of `\afterpage` is processed in a group. The difference is that `\thispagestyle` acts globally, while `\pagestyle` doesn't.

Comment: egrep's analysis is correct.  There is discussion of this on page 17 of the fancyhdr documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `afterpage` package documentation is not explicit on the subject, but it turns out that the token list given as argument to `\afterpage` is processed inside a group, so declarations inside it are undone at the end of the group, unless expressly made `\global`.

The effect of `\thispagestyle` is indeed global: its definition is

```
\def\thispagestyle#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ps@#1}%
    \undefinedpagestyle
    {\global\@specialpagetrue\gdef\@specialstyle{#1}}}
```

On the other hand, the definition of `\pagestyle` is

```
\def\pagestyle#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ps@#1}%
    \undefinedpagestyle
    {\@nameuse{ps@#1}}}
```

and therefore one can't say `\global\pagestyle{pagestyleB}`: the actual assignments are performed when executing the instructions contained in `\ps@pagestyleB`.

As Andrew Swann remarks in his comment, the problem is discussed on page 17 of `fancyhdr`'s documentation.

Depending on the intended application, the problem could be solved by using a "conditionally defined" page style and using `\afterpage` to globally change the conditional's truth value. Say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,afterpage,lipsum}

\newif\ifpsB
\fancypagestyle{pagestyleAB}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[C]{pagestyleA}% Header
  \fancyfoot[C]{\ifpsB B\else A\fi--\thepage}% Footer
}
\pagestyle{pagestyleAB}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}\lipsum[1-20]
\clearpage
\afterpage{\global\psBtrue}\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Here pages 1 and 3–5 will have “A—#” at their footer, pages 6–8 will have “B—#” and page 2 will have the empty page style.