# How to put fancy header on all pages except the first page?

Tags: fancyhdr

I am trying to put fancyhdr custom style on all pages except first one, but it either shows up on all of them, or on none, I can't make this style to go from second page, im new to latex, so any help is welcome.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I am using article

Comment: The default is for the first page to be set using `\thispagestyle{plain}` (even under `\maketitle`). However, if you add to your preamble `\thispagestyle{plain}\pagestyle{fancy}`, you will always get a `plain` *first* page, and `fancy` *subsequent* pages. If not, something's amiss, and you'll have to show us what you're doing, because you might be doing it wrong...

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly, first is plain, others are my own style, thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 11):

The default page style - `plain` - is used throughout `article`, even if `\maketitle` is used. To be sure though, you could add

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

to your preamble, which will ensure the first page uses `plain` (as a result of `\thispagestyle`) and subsequent pages use `fancy` (as a result of `\pagestyle`; `\thispagestyle` overrides `\pagestyle`).

Here's a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
\fancyhead[L]{Left header}\fancyhead[C]{Centre header}\fancyhead[R]{Right header}
\fancyfoot[L]{Left footer}\fancyfoot[C]{Centre footer}\fancyfoot[R]{Right footer}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\title{My title}
\author{My author}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Another option might be to use [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) which you can use to set the page style of page *following* the one containing the `\afterpage` command. However, `\afterpage` sets its contents in a group, which doesn't allow a regular `\pagestyle` to survive. For that, you could use some other trickery, as discussed in [Page styles only work for `\thispagestyle` under `afterpage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85729/5764).

Comment: how would you add page number?

Comment: @botenvouwer: The page number should be available as `\thepage`. So add that wherever you want to see the page number.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\thispagestyle{empty}` to remove all header and footer (even the page number of the first page}. It is very useful when you want to make a page title for a report or a thesis.

You can use this command anywhere in your document.